# How can I automate a test that sends multiple mock intents to an Android activity?

Tags: android, junit, automated-tests, android-intent, instrumentation

I am trying to send mock intents to an Android activity via the Android instrumentation tools and Android JUnit in Eclipse.

I am able to successfully create a test that sends one `Intent` to an `Activity`, but I want to automate this and send several consecutive `Intents` so I can test the `Activity` with many pieces of data put in as an "extra" in the `Intent`.
My code (which works for a single Intent) is as follows:

```
public class SearchTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SearchResults> {

    private ListActivity mActivity;
    private ArrayList<String> testManifest = new ArrayList<String>();
    TextView tv; 


    public SearchTest() {
        super("org.fdroid.fdroid", SearchResults.class);
    }//SearchTest

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        setUpTestManifest();
        super.setUp();
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
        i.setClassName("org.fdroid.fdroid", "org.fdroid.fdroid.SearchResults");
        i.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, testManifest.get(0));
        setActivityIntent(i);
        mActivity = getActivity();
        tv = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }//setUp

    public void testSearchResult(){
        assertTrue(mActivity.getListView().getCount() > 0);
    }//testSearchResult

    public void setUpTestManifest(){
        //populate the test manifest
        testManifest.add("Sample Key Word 1");
        testManifest.add("Sample Key Word 2");
        testManifest.add("Sample Key Word 3");
    }//setupManifest

}//SearchTest
```

How can I make this work where I can have hundreds of items in the `testManifest` and create an Intent and test for each of those items?

Comment: Would be nice if you let us know if bellow answer is what you been looking for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried pulling out the launching of the activity out of the setUp code and into a loop within your test method? Example,

```
protected void setUp() {
    setUpTestManifest();
    super.setUp();
} 

public void testSearchResult(){
    for (String query : testManifest) {
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
        i.setClassName("org.fdroid.fdroid", "org.fdroid.fdroid.SearchResults");
        i.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
        setActivityIntent(i);
        mActivity = getActivity();
        tv = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.description);
        assertTrue(mActivity.getListView().getCount() > 0);
        mActivity.finish();  // close the activity
        setActivity(null);   // forces next call of getActivity to re-open the activity
    }
}
```

-Dan